# How to detect if ionic PWA is installed on desktop (not the browser)?

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, desktop, platform

thanks in advance for the help. I've looked everywhere and I couldn't find a proper way to check this.

### **Scenario:**

I've installed the ionic PWA and try to check the platforms to determine if the app is install or not. For mobile is ok, because I can check:

```
if ((!this.platform.is('pwa') && this.platform.is('mobile'))) {...}
```

BUT for desktop I don't have a way to know if the app is install on the device or not...(as "PWA" doesn't seems to work when the device is not a mobile one)

---

Meaby I'm missing something out of this docs:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform
THANKS very much :)

Comment: u can also detect if this.platform.is('desktop') && !this.platform.is('mobile') {...}

Comment: right, but how do you know if the app is actually installed? I'm trying to do this becasue I only want to share a "Better user experience" on the desktop view...

Comment: Are u using electron for users to install there app as desktop app? If so then u also check if this.platform.is('electron') else i need to know the wrapper u are using to preview ur app as desktop application to see the conditions

Comment: Nop, I'm not using electron. Is the PWA that gets installed. So sadly I cannot do the check his.platform.is('electron')...

Comment: Ok, if u can inspect the installed pwa on ur computer, see the html tag, it should contain some classes related to platform like pwa or desktop or web or mobile something like that, and do same on web for sure there will be some changes in classes between the 2, so in this way u can get to know the condition u should put to detect each one where it is run .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mostafa Harb! You've pointed me in the rigth direction!
For those who wants to check if the user is accesing via the desktop and the app is not installed (at least with Ionic 5 version...), you can do:

```
const isPWAInstalledOnDesktop: boolean = document.getElementsByClassName('plt-pwa').length > 0;
If(!isPWAInstalledOnDesktop && this.platform.is('desktop')){...}
```